# How can I print an alert message on screen which tells Quiz Questions and ends in a flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make simple quiz app in flutter. I will save all questions in class. And, then I will use conditional statement to check if a question is correct.

print  (check)icon on screen else print (close).

When questions end, I want to print AlertDialog which says that the quiz question has ended. And, then reset the quiz.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this would be of interest https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

Answer (score 0):

You can show [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) at end of questions, that after navigate to home page. like this:

```dart
await showDialog(
      context: this.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
      },
    );
Navigator.of(context).pop(); // this line navigate to prevues page(like home)
```